# Preventing the back press action in a fragment while leaving the SingleTop activty alive

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app has two activities, ActivityA and ActivityB. ActivityB has two Fragments, Fragment1 and Fragment2.

In the mobile:
ActivityA => ActivityB | Fragment1 => Fragment2

In Tablet:
ActivityA => ActivityB | Fragment1 && Fragment2 (together)

what I want to do is:
I want to ensure that when the back button pressed in mobile while Fragment2 is active, the app goes back to Fragment1 given that the app is singleTop; i.e. I want activity to be alive all the time.

I used the folowing code, The problem is:
when the back button clicked in a mobile device, Fragment1 starts but disappears shortly and ActivityA takes the screen.

How can I correct my code?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    if (!DeviceType.isTablet(ActivityB.this) && Fragment2 != null) { // DeviceType.isTablet() returns "true" if the device is Tablet

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("clickedFragment1Item", clickedFragment1Item);

        startFragment1(bundle); // A method to start Fragment1

    }
}
```

Comment: add an `else` to your `if` statement and move `super.onBackPressed();` into that block - you're allowing the `super` class also deal with the click everytime the back button is pressed - you only want this to happen when it doesn't suit your `if` statement

Comment: @Mark Keen, this is what I exactly want. Thank you!